# why is the following C++ code giving segmentation fault for this specific input?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n
    cin.ignore(32767,'\n');
    string arr[n],temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        getline(cin,temp);
        arr[i]=temp;
    }
}
```

**Input**:
10
tourist
petr
wjmzbmr
yeputons
vepifanov
scottwu
oooooooooooooooo
subscriber
rowdark
tankengineer

My code is running fine for all the other inputs(even when n=10) but for this specific input(mentioned above), it is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: Where is `a` declared? Also note that variable length arrays are not standard C++, but a compiler extension.

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: This is non-standard C++, due to VLAs not being supported by C++ standard.

Comment: As other said, VLAs aren't supported by C++ standard. Use dynamic array or some kind of container (e.g. `vector`) instead.

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled because _a[i]=temp_ rather than _arr[i]=temp_, so are you sure *that* code crash ? The only thing I can see may be not expected for you is the first time _getline_ will return an empty line because it will read the \n after 10

Comment: Given that the shown code is fake code and not real code, for the reasons already stated, any attempt to figure out the answer is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't possibly compile as-is and you are using [VLA:s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) that aren't supported by C++ so it's hard to reproduce your problem. Try avoiding it by using a C++ container, like a `std::vector`, instead. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore(); // discard the '\n' still in the buffer

    // declare a standard C++ container, like a vector of strings
    std::vector<std::string> arr(n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        std::getline(std::cin, arr[i]);
    }

    std::cout << "VALUES:\n";
    for(auto& s : arr) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```